# Simplest circuit to reliably produce two voltage peaks, then nothing

Tags: circuit-design

I'm trying to make a circuit with basic components and simple IC's that starts low, produces two pulses of high returning to low in between, in ideally a square wave though anything that doesn't bounce around between peaks should be fine, then returns to low indefinitely.

Duty cycle and frequency don't really matter, though the pulses must be a minimum of 0.2s wide with a specific 2.3s spacing between them, and ideally the spacing between them would be easily changed, as this is the most important variable I'm trying to play with.

**What I've tried so far**

- Op amp and two RC circuits to produce repeating sine-like wave — Doesn't stop
- 555 circuit in astable mode — Doesn't stop
- 555 circuit in monostable mode — Doesn't repeat

Note: I'd like to ideally avoid the 555, but if that's really not possible it's not too much of a concern

Comment: What triggers the sequence?  Forcing the circuit to stop after the second output pulse smells like a flipflop in there somewhere.  One monostable so the two output pulses are identical, one adjustable delay timer between them, and a ff to count to two and disable the circuit.

Comment: My first thought off the top of my head is to use the 555 to clock a couple of D-flops in series, then use the Q bar output of the last flop to disable the pulses via an AND gate. Or something along those lines.

Comment: OR, three monostables in series, with the first and third trimmed to be identical.  All of this can be done with one CMOS Schmitt trigger hex inverter.  74AC14 for 5 V, CD40106 for 3-15 V.

Comment: In the 21st century this is a job for a microcontroller ... it'll be quicker, cheaper, smaller, more reliable ...

Comment: 555 with flip flops

Comment: @VoltageSpike How do you mean?

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist actually it works better with three 555 timers in series and an or gate, you can adjust the timing widths on all three. You could do this with one 555 timer and some logic but that takes more time to figure out and is beyond my pay grade

Answer (score 2):

The *simplest* circuit, I believe, would be to use a microcontroller.

Many microcontrollers have a built-in oscillator and will run when powered up, without any external components.

This would of course require some basic programming and may not be the simplest *solution*, depending on your situation.

Personally, my approach for something like this would be an ATtiny10 or PIC10F320. With a ZIF programmer it'd be programmed and ready to go in less time than it would take me to breadboard a 555.

To change the timing I would either add a potentiometer (both of the above have ADCs) or simply socket the IC so I can easily pull it out and reprogram it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a two shot, there are three one shots in series, one triggers the other. The ouputs of the first and last are 'or-ed' together to create the double pulse. The bottom trace is the output of the or gate, which shows a two shot from one trigger. Top trace is the trigger. The spacing between the pulses and the space in between can be changed with the RC combination of each 555 timer

[image]